# Java Server redirecting too many times. Need help pinpointing new URL

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I'm working on application that connects to okcupid.com and logs in with a valid username and password.  I've had it running fine during testing, but recently something must have changed on the okc server side because I'm getting an error that says the server redirected too many times (2) (see error output below).

Up until recently, the code used `(http://www.okcupid.com/locquery?func=query&query=" + zip)` I can still get output if i go to this URL or use the code that learning loop posted below, but my app, which login with an account stopped working.  I think something changed with the cookie.  Most of the error messages  lead back to the location ID.  Can someone explain how to use Chrome or Firefox to pinpoint this URL while logging in to okc through a browser so that I can make the apprpopriate changes in my code?  Thanks in advance.

```
  java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too many  times (20)
     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1469)
     at okc.jurl.run(jurl.java:149)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at okc.Utils.find(Utils.java:60)
    at okc.LocationAssistant.findLocid(LocationAssistant.java:125)
    at okc.AccountManager.findLocid(AccountManager.java:390)
    at okc.OkcView.getLocid(OkcView.java:3088)
    at okc.OkcView.login(OkcView.java:2924)
    at okc.OkcView.access$20(OkcView.java:2912)
    at okc.OkcView$15.actionPerformed(OkcView.java:1114)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6414)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3275)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6179)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2084)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4776)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2142)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4604)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4618)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4279)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4209)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2128)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2492)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4604)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:690)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:687)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL to fetch values seems to be missing `func` keyword.

For example, following URL worked:

```
https://www.okcupid.com/locquery?func=query&query=14850

{"status" : 0, "ZipCode" : "14850", "query" : "14850", "locid" : 4333788, 
"results" : [{"locid" : 4333788, "text" : "Ithaca"}]}
```

Where as following didn't:

```
https://www.okcupid.com/locquery?=query&query=14850

{"query" : ""}
```

---

Mainly check if there is any change in your proxy settings. Following program worked with proper proxy settings.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        //Following line needs to be enabled accordingly if you are using proxy
        //If you are enabling proxy, replace proxy.com with your proxy address    
        //System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "proxy.com");
        //System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "80");

        URL oracle = 
            new URL("https://www.okcupid.com/locquery?func=query&query=14850");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually had the func in my code. i accidentally left it out when writing the post.  I've edited and updated.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @dbconfession Now the answer is updated. You can try with proxy settings and using https instead of http

Comment: thanks. I'll take a look when I get home. Is it possible to contact you via messenger or email if I need further help? Ultimately I'll post here to confirm if it worked and give you credit.

Comment: Ok. I think I need to clarify a bit.  The output of this basically just show what I would  get if I pasted that URL into a browser. I already know the link works.  I'm having a problem running my app, which logs my account into occupied.com, but which has always worked in the past.  They changed something with their login cookie I'm sure and I can't figure out how to fix it.  Can you post a program which shows how to login with a valid account?  I'll update the original to clarify.